# Ghost external HDD (OSX): nowhere to be seen

Tags: macos, external-hard-drive, data-recovery, hard-drive-failure

I need to retrieve a hard drive, which was used on Mac, but when connecting the drive it boots and lights-up, except that it doesn't mount, in fact it doesn't appear in my USB bus connection despite booting-up and making noises when connecting it.

Any idea why?

Comment: Any idea/first diagnostic when the drive is not appearing on OSX USB Bus information?